# Difference between javascript date.valueOf() and java date.getTime()

Tags: javascript, java

Currently I am trying to convert a date calculation from javascript to java, since I want to use it for Android development. So in javascript I was using the method `date.valueOf()`, which converts the date to the milliseconds that passed since January 1, 1970. In java the method with the same funcionality is called `date.getTime()`. In the java and javascript documentation the description is exactly the same, but when I am inserting the same date, I am getting two completely different values.
For example:

**Java `getTime()`**

```
Date date = new Date(2011, 10, 1);
System.out.println(date.getTime()); //prints: 61278249600000
```

**Javascript `valueOf()`**

```
const date = new Date(2011, 10, 1);
console.log(date.valueOf()); //prints: 1320102000000
```

So my questions are:

- Why is this happening? (or what did I wrong?)
- How can I correct the code?

It would be awesome if somebody can help me.

Comment: Do not longer use the old java Date API.

Comment: And how should I then convert the date to milliseconds since January 1, 1970?

Comment: Read about the java.time API

Comment: [Tutorial link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Comment: I recommend that in Java you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: In Java use `LocalDate.of(2011, Month.NOVEMBER, 1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`. In my time zone, Europe/Copenhagen, it gives the same number as you get in JavaScript, 1 320 102 000 000. The result in other time zones will differ by up to about 13 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discrepancy isn't between Java's `getTime` and JavaScript's `valueOf`, it's the [Java `Date` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,int)). The year parameter is years **since 1900**. So [the equivalent Java code](https://ideone.com/1TdFrs) would be:

```java
Date date = new Date(110, 10, 1);
//                   ^−−− 2010 - 1900
```

This is one of the ***many*** reasons not to use the `java.util.Date` class.